# Selecting from comments and images table for each article in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an articles table that and I am displaying it in the homepage in a while loop. Inside the while loop I want to display the comments count and images count for each article.

It is working for me now, but it is three queries in total, I am trying to combine it in the first query and then just display all of them in one while loop. Here is what I am trying to achieve:[Articles page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsxCU.png)

The current format I am following:

```
//a represents articles table, c represents comments table, i represents image table

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT a.a_id, a.title, a.datetime, a.user_id FROM a ORDER BY a.datetime DESC");

while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query){
   $imageQ = msqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(image_path), image_path FROM i WHERE a_id = '$fetch['a_id']'");
$imageFetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($imageQ);
$commentQ = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(comment_id) FROM c WHERE a_id = '$fetch['a_id']'");
$commentFetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commentQ);
}
```

I want to cram all of these queries into one single query that fetches the article and comments count and image count for each article and the  first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images and comments are *separate* dimensions of the data.  So, you have to be careful about how to bring them together.  In your case, you can aggregate the values before doing the joins:

```
SELECT a.a_id, a.title, a.datetime, a.user_id,
       i.num_images, c.num_comments
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a_id, COUNT(image_path) as num_images
      FROM i
      GROUP BY a_id
     ) i
     ON i.a_id = a.a_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a_id, COUNT(comment_id) as num_comments
      FROM c
      GROUP BY a_id
     ) c
     ON c.a_id = a.a_id
ORDER BY a.datetime DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff I am using your method now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql nested queries something like

> SELECT  a.*,tab1.*,tab2.* FROM a INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM b ) as tab1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM c) as tab2

Hope this can get you to get desired output.

Thanks